# how can i show invisible primefaces panel in client side

Tags: primefaces

I create a panel and set its visible attribute to false as following:

```
<p:panel widgetVar="myPanel" visible="false" >
```

Now i have a commandButton and i will when user click on it the myPanel change to visible mode and user can see it. my button is like this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Show Panel" oncomplete="myPanel.show()" />
```

But primefaces(4) panel just have 2 client side methods:

- close
- toggle

do you have any solution for this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why client side?

The normal way with JSF (and Primefaces) is to bind `visible` (or `rendered`, the procedure is mostly similar) to a bean property, change this property on click of button and update the component. Something like this:

Bean:

```
private boolean visible = false;

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}
```

Xhtml:

```
<p:panel id="mp" widgetVar="myPanel" visible="#{bean.visible}" >

<p:commandButton value="Show Panel" action="#{bean.setVisible(true)}" update="mp" />
```

Comment: thanks @JaqenH'ghar. but your code need ajax request and communicate with server. i will do it completely in client side. i search and find primefaces doesn't have any function for show. i solve it with jquery show and hide method.